# What's the best practice to design a table that would have different fields on different conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, psql

I need advice in creating tables where there would be different fields based on a condition. I'm pretty new to psql, so I don't really know if I'm going the right way and would appreciate any tips / advice!

Currently I have a table to represent a `meeting_note`, which can either be a voice recording OR a text.

When the meeting note is of type `text`, it must have a `meeting_content`, and can have an optional `meeting_summary`. `audio_source` should be null.

When the meeting note is of type `audio`, it must have an `audio_source` and the fields `meeting_content` and `meeting_summary` should be null.

I was also thinking of creating two tables - one for type audio and another for text, but there is a `unique` constraint on `created_at` which represents a date like May 11th. I wasn't sure how to add this constraint between two tables.

Here are the fields for the table `meeting_note`

```
id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
meeting_id integer REFERENCES meeting(id),
meeting_note_type enum('audio', 'text') NOT NULL, 
meeting_content text, 
summary varchar(255),
created_at varchar(10) NOT NULL,
recording_source varchar(255)
```

and the constraints:

```
UNIQUE (to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD')), 
CHECK (NOT (meeting_note_type = 'text' AND meeting_content IS NULL)), 
CHECK (NOT (meeting_note_type = 'audio' AND audio_source IS NULL)), 
CHECK (NOT (meeting_content IS NULL AND audio_source IS NULL), 
CHECK (NOT (meeting_content IS NOT NULL AND audio_source IS NOT NULL), 
CHECK (NOT (audio_source IS NOT NULL AND summary IS NOT NULL))
```

Appreciate any help on this. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common approaches to this problem - using a table-per-type and using one table for everything. The approach you describe in the question is one table for everything; your definition is pretty accurate.

Here is how to do a table-per-type solution: make a "master" table for all notes, and then a table for each note sub-type, like this:

```
create table note_master(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
    meeting_id integer REFERENCES meeting(id),
    created_at varchar(10) NOT NULL
)

create table note_text (
    id serial REFERENCES note_master(id),
    meeting_content text, 
    summary varchar(255),
)

create table note_audio (
    id serial REFERENCES note_master(id),
    recording_source varchar(255)
)
```

To query for everything you do left-outer joins to `note_text` and `note_audio`. This approach lets you skip the `enum` because you can always figure out what kind of note it is by examining the results of the join.